# 'str' object has no attribute 'validate' Django ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So i been looking on internet and I didn't  find an answer

I want to register all my models with their respective modeladmin automaticaly.
So i did this:

```
  for model in get_models(get_app('maksc')):
      modeladmin = ('' +  str(model) + 'Admin')
      admin.site.register(model, modeladmin)
```

But it doesnt seem to work , if you need more info i will give it to you.

```
"<class 'maksc.models.Header'>Admin"
```

Anyway i cant find a way to fix it

Comment: Are you doing this in `admin.py` where the model admins are defined?

Comment: Yes , i have. I dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually prefer to be explicit about registering models in the admin, but:

```
for model in get_models(get_app('maksc')):
    modeladmin = locals().get(model.__name__ + 'Admin')
    if modeladmin:
        admin.site.register(model, modeladmin)
```

It uses `model.__name__` to get the model class name as a string, joins it with `Admin` and gets the Model Admin class from [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

Comment: It worked :D , and how should i do if i want to do another for to create the modeladmins ?

Comment: @Maks that's a separate question - provide more details and elaborate it into the new question - so more people can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Why ? in that same for i want it to create the models , that cant be done ?

Comment: @Maks well, this code assumes you have model admins defined in the local scope. The purpose of it is to register every model that has a model admin defined, plus it assumes that the naming is `Modelname` + `Admin`.

Comment: @Maks initially I thought you have ModelAdmins defined for each model. Ok, you can autoregister all the models using [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2066/).